# Fetch antd card value onclick in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an antd gridstyle Card which consists of some cards. When I click on a paricular card how can fetch the content in the `result function` ?

On Clicking **Mark** card, I want to fetch the value `Mark` but I have no Idea how to do that. Please suggest a workaround.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Card } from "antd";

const gridStyle = {width: "25%",textAlign: "center"};
function result(){
  alert(1) // HOW CAN I GET "MARK" HERE??????  <---------------------
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Card title="Card Title">
      <Card.Grid style={gridStyle} onClick={result}>Mark</Card.Grid>
      <Card.Grid style={gridStyle} onClick={result}>Jeff</Card.Grid>
  </Card>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `event.target.innerText` inside your `result` function:

```
function result(event) {
  console.log(event.target.innerText) 
}
```